# Get the data attribute of a div that WASN'T clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs.

```
<div class="my_thing" data-id="123"></div>

<div class="my_thing" data-id="529"></div>
```

When a div is clicked, I want to get the `data-id` for the clicked div, and the `data-id` for the one that wasn't clicked. So I end up with this object:

```
{
  clicked_id = 123,
  not_clicked_id = 529
}
```

How can I do this? This is what I have so far.

```
$('.my_thing').click(function(){
  var clicked_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var not_clicked_id = ?????
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there will be only 2 `.my_thing` elements then you can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not) like

```js
var $divs = $('.my_thing').click(function() {
  var clicked_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var not_clicked_id = $divs.not(this).attr('data-id');

  log(clicked_id + '-' + not_clicked_id)
});


var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).prependTo($log)
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_thing" data-id="123">123</div>
<div class="my_thing" data-id="529">529</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```